# How to check dynamic javascript value with Jquery with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am stuck on this, please help!

I have an external Javascript that inserts code on my page. Among other things it inserts an image wrapped in a div. *I do not have control over the script*, but I would like to change the image path/url using Jquery.

This is what I have done:

```
$('.ProductImage img').attr('src',function(index,attr){
          return attr.replace('small','original');
    });
```

Works like a charm in all browsers except IE.

When checking the selector with alert(), IE returns %Thumbnail% which is the Javascript variable/object. I have tried wrapping my script in a timeout to allow IE to finish loading but no luck.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of IE? jQuery known issue: `Simple class selectors like ".myClass" fail in IE 5.5. Workaround: select "div.myClass" instead.`

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned - IE8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your code inside `$(function(){ .. })` so that it will run after the document finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

If your script is not loaded by the time your code gets executed you could try putting the code inside window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
    replaceImages();
};

function replaceImages(){
    $('.ProductImage img').attr('src',function(index,attr){
        return attr.replace('small','original');
    });
}
```